# Howe to capture UIView top UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimage

i have `UIView` which displays the Graph..now I need to capture it to the `UIImage` and I googled it and got the below code.but if i use this in my code its not work.even if I use breakpoint compiler does not reach to this.I am using this in my `UIView` .where I am going wrong?

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this method..?

Comment: ya where to call this now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a screenshot of any view or whole screen of the iPhone app with below method

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

//hide controls if needed
CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

And call it like bellow...

```
UIImage *tempImageSave=[self captureView];
```

and you can also save this image  with this bellow line for photo album..

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempImageSave,nil,nil,nil);
```

and you can also save this image  with this bellow line for Document Directory..

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImageSave);
NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",1];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
[fileMan createFileAtPath:pdfFileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

If the view contains the layer images or some graphics related data then use below method.

```
-(UIImage *)convertViewToImage:(UIView *)viewTemp
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewTemp.bounds.size);
    [viewTemp drawViewHierarchyInRect:viewTemp.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;

}
```

And use this method like below.

```
UIImage *tempImageSave = [self convertViewToImage:yourView];
```

I hope this helpful for you.

Comment: need to use this code in UIView right?? but property View is not found error

Comment: hey dude see which you want to capture the view?? and what you want this image?? you want to save this image in device directory??

Comment: @Christien just put above method in your .m file dude and then call it like my above code also add this captured image in UIImageView and check its display the proper photo which you captured dude.. :)

Comment: @Christien dude my last line save your captured view image in your directory , very simple

Comment: @ParasJoshi its save in to Device Photo Album not in Xcode simulator Document Directory :)

Comment: @NitinGohel ya ya dude Photo Album dude...  and also in simulatore its save this image just try you bro.. try kar ne yaar.. ;)

Comment: kari atle j to kahyu bhai ke document directory manathi avtu Simulatore photo album ma ave che document director mate filemanager thi savekaravvi pade ne dost ... :)

Comment: oh ok ok mane thyu k tu m kahe 6 k aa simulator ma work j nti kartu means save j nti kartu m ok ok .. but tu kya re 6 and kai company ma 6??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21741/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 1):

you can save image of View like this way and store image in to Document Directory:-

```
-(void)SaveViewAsImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

        UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
        NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",1];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [fileMan createFileAtPath:pdfFileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];

}
```

Your image save in Document Directory :)

**Download this demo**

http://www.sendspace.com/file/gjxa82

Comment: need to use this code in UIView right?? but property View is not found error

Comment: you put your Defined View in "self.view.bounds.size" to yourVIew.bounds.size

Comment: sorry i forget to put one line  [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

Comment: check my upadated answer download the demo and check it image store in document directory :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code it may be help you

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```