# FTP Downloading very slow in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ftp

I am having an app in which I am using FTPHelper.h and FTPHelper.m files.

I am downloading the images from the dedicated server using FTP.

It works fine in my project but the images downloaded from server are very slow.

I have 50 images of 4.5mb to download and it takes almost 4 to 5 minutes to download.

I have imported two files FTPHelper.h and FTPHelper.m in my project and below is the code I am using.

```
-(void)getdata
{
    [FTPHelper sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [FTPHelper sharedInstance].uname = BASE_USERNAME;
    [FTPHelper sharedInstance].pword = BASE_PASSWORD;
    [FTPHelper sharedInstance].urlString = BASE_URL;
   [FTPHelper list:BASE_URL];
    [FTPHelper download:file];
}
```

Is there any other way I can reduce the time for it?

Thanks...

Comment: what you want?? display that images in UITableView???

Comment: No. I am downloading images from server and saving that images on documents directory.

Comment: try to use AsyncImageView i post link about that in answer see.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AsyncImageView` for download that Images in background from web..

See Information about that from [THIS LINK](http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/408/AsyncImageView/).

and Get Demo from [AsyncImageView Link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

Also see some different code from this link [ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way you can reduce the file size of these images on server? Since its 4 to 5 MB, most likey these are PNG files. Try saving them as JPG with 80% quality and you would reduce significant size. (This would be a lossy compression thought).

If FTP is not mandatory, there are alternates to downloading, Eg: use URL to access the image.(HTTP instead of FTP).