# why the image become zoom while converting view to image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have uiview and i want to convert that view to image which is working quite well but when i pressed the home button of iphone and run the app again the image become zoom in .Here is my code to converting view to image.

[image: When the app 1st time run]

[image: After pressing the home button and run the app again.]

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {
        CGRect rect = [myview bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [myview.layer renderInContext:context];
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return img;

 }
 checkImage.image = [self captureView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here this code is not wrong but you used some other object instead of whole view . i don't know but try to use that view bounds in which that whole Image display.. See my answer same like your this answer from this bellow link..

[how to capture uiview top uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049796/howe-to-capture-uiview-top-uiview/14049828#14049862)

Also try with `self.view` instead of `myView` in your code.

add this code instead of your `checkImage.image = [self captureView];` line..

```
 UIImageView *imgTempHeader = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[self captureView]];
 imgTempHeader.frame = self.view.frame;
 [self.view addSubview:imgTempHeader];
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgTempHeader];
```

Comment: myView is another view on main view

Comment: yes i know but i just want to check that if you use self.view instead of myView in your all code then its get image of whole view or not.. do that and let me know , also use my code instead of your from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049796/howe-to-capture-uiview-top-uiview/

Comment: @parash joshi same issue

Comment: @iOSdeveloper hey i update code with example please try out with that code and let me know...

Comment: @Parash Joshi after pressing the Home Button of iPhone and run the app again it zoom

Comment: its means your `checkImage` `UIImageView` is set default with some zoomscale with programming or from xib , post code related to `checkImage` please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34899/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating the context in a way which uses the scale of the device:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
```

Then when you display the image in the image view ensure that the content mode is set to prevent scaling.

Comment: What is the size of `myview` and `checkImage`?

Comment: both having same size

Comment: Any scroll views? The image generation seems ok, I guess it's something else about your views of the way you configure the image display.

Comment: any solution regarding this problem

Comment: Show all information about your views, superviews, configuration, source image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34902/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-wain)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is with setting up imageViews in IB. I assume checkImage is an instance of UIImageView?

If you were displaying an image in a UIImageView and had only set the view mode to center in interface builder it would appear zoomed in if the image was large.

Have a look at this way to process your image first:

```
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:myCGImageRef scale:myZoomSCale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
```

Of course you will need to give it a CGImageRef for your image. Over to you or somebody else for that.